# Images will not work in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku

I am building a rails app in Rails 4.0.0 and my images work just fine in production. I am using this code:

```
<img alt="" src="assets/ski-large2.jpg">
```

But when I push it to Heroku the images do not appear. I have tried changing the path to the following:

```
<img alt="" src="/app/assets/ski-large1.jpg">
```

Still does not work. In my console I get 404 file not found errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some recommendations.

1. place images under assets/images directory
2. instead of explicitly using `<img></img>` tags use:

   ```
    <%= image_tag 'ski-large1.jpg' %> 
    <%= image_tag 'ski-large2.jpg' %>
   ```