# Ruby on Rails / Heroku Images not rendering in a staging application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app running in heroku, to render images in the config/production.rb I entered this  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compile = true and I was able to see my images fine, when I created a test app the images were not being rendered. Got any suggestions? I am rendering the images ">

Comment: Please could you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post? In particular, please at least include the critical lines of code - such as where the image gets rendered in the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images will not work in Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715919/images-will-not-work-in-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

If you are upload images and wants to display it on Heroku application then it won't be happen because heroku is readonly system. You have to upload images to another server like AWS S3 or cloudinary using paperclip/carrierwave gem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help forgot to seed my test database, thanks for all your help really appreciate it